# Footwear for swimming pool and change room

Tags: health, swimming, foot-care

I do a lot of swimming and am often in change rooms. What is good to wear on your feet? I'm thinking of getting flip flops or sandals and was wondering if there's any type in particular that are well suited for use in a swimming pool deck and change room. I once heard flip flops are bad for you as you tend to scrunch your toes to grip them. I probably should get cheap ones as if I'm leaving them by the side of the pool I can't keep an eye on them when I get in. The main reason I'm getting them is for sanitary reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a pair of Haviana flip flops. They're cheap and are perfect for wearing around the swimming pool.

I really don't know why you'd scrunch your toes wearing flip flops if they fit you properly. That only really happens if they're too big. If you're worried about that, just maybe go for a smaller size.